# Understanding coordinates in Netherlands dataset?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, netherlands

I have data on specific addresses of companies in the Netherlands. The dataset also provides the coordinates but they look different from what I am used to see. I converted some of the addresses into the conventional coordinates and the difference is as below

y(from data),        x (from data),     x (from conversion), y (from conversion)

391550,              36169,            51.517316,           3.898328,

362102.741,           57704.823,         51.23535,            3.97432,

365154.862,           53111.293,         51.26986   ,         3.956236,

Can anyone help me as how to convert these (weird) coordinates into the conventional coordinate system. When I used the batch conversion, many addresses did not give the right coordinates and it is a very tedious job to convert the addresses manually. Manual address to coordinate conversion give the right coordinates.

Comment: Sure, these are from the Netherlands.

Comment: Did the data source provide information on the coordinate reference system used? Can you explain how you did the manual conversion and the batch conversion? What tools, and what processes did you follow. Its hard to even guess without more information.

Comment: @Menno I am not sure that it is RD (see http://www.regiolab-delft.nl/road_mapping/rd_wgs84.cgi?coordinate1=391550&coordinate2=36169&format=text&retrieve=Submit+query for the first pair)

Comment: I used GPS visualizer for batch conversion (http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/). Later used google gps coordiantes for manual conversion (http://www.gps-coordinates.net/) The dataset does not provide the information on the coordinate system used, that is unfortunate.

Comment: @radouxju I'm sorry, you're right. I overlooked it, comment deleted. It's not WGS84 UTM 31 N, neither is it ETRS 1989. That's all I can think of at the minute. Have a look at http://georepository.com/ where you can search for coordinate systems and projections on the map. You might be able to find one that fits your coordinates.

Comment: I think they're in EPSG:28992, Amersfoort / RD New.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the suggestion by mkennedy for EPSG:28992, the points are located this way:

[image]

which does not fit well, unless the WGS84 coordinates are rough or wrong. There is also an `Amersfoort RD Old` projection, but that is far off.

Looking closer, the RD New points perfectly match to adresses in Openstreetmap, while the WGS84 are just road junctions; the lower two ones of the same street, but way off. Maybe the geocoder does not know house numbers.

If I take the address from the one top left into the Geocoder, it returns
51.500416, 3.675717. Openstreetmap search returns 51.5004159, 3.6757169; which makes both fit perfectly.

---

You can batch convert the coordinates from Amersfoort RD New to WGS84 using GDAL cs2cs.

Put your coordinates sorted by X Y into a text file named `in.txt`, create a batch file with this content:

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:28992 +to +init=epsg:4326 in.txt >out.txt
```

and run the batch inside the GDAL SDK or OSGEO4W shell.

Comment: Thank you so much for such elaborate help. I am trying the solution now.

Comment: @AnreJ Thanks. I am pretty new to GIS and I was using QGIS. I tried converting the coordinates from Amersfoort RD to WGS84 but I cannot see the outcome in my attribute table. I have no clue about using GDAL. I tried looking into the tutorials but didn't help much. How can I download a program or something to convert theses coordinates in batch

Comment: The values in the attribute table will not be changed by reprojection, only the coordinates. You can add new geometry columns with the reprojected coordinates using `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Export/Add Geometry Columns` or the field calculator or the MMQGIS plugin. Outside QGIS, you can use cs2cs, either in the OSGEO4W shell that comes with QGIS or separately from http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/ if you are using Windows.

Comment: I highly appreciate your help. When I try the MMQGIS plugin solution, I get the csv file with no coordinates but 'inf'instead in all the rows. Do you know any reason why this would happen?

Comment: Your solution with OSGEO4W shell worked out. Thanks a lot really for your help.